# How to fine tune the network automatically in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

How to tune the network automatically instead of adjusting the number of  hidden layers and epochs everytime manually?  (Using Keras)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

seed = 9
numpy.random.seed(seed)

from pandas import read_csv
filename = 'BBCN.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(filename)

array = dataframe.values
x = array[:,0 : 11]
y = array[:, 11]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(11, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', z = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))          

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer ='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y,nb_epoch = 50, batch_size = 10 )

scores = model.evaluate(x,y)
print("%s, %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

The result I need is to show the process and the percentage of the accuracy.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Just try to learn the way to fine tune automatically, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a simple loop over some hyperparameters and train with these for some epochs and then compare the results.

You can also look into grid search which is a more systematic approach. Basically you setup a function that creates a model and use it with a set of hyperparameters that you want to try out and an array of values. For more details and boilerplate code [I recommend this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/).

Comment: if you really want all things to be done automatically grid search can be one of the solutions. But it is very time consuming, generally when the dataset is large or model is complex. I myself do not prefer grid search. I like to tune the hyperparameters myself.